# How to scrape data behind a login

Tags: python, web-scraping, nlp, web-crawler

I am going to extract posts in a forum, named positive wellbeing during isolation" in HealthUnlocked.com
I can extract posts without login, but I cannot extract posts with logging. I used " url = 'https://solaris.healthunlocked.com/posts/positivewellbeing/popular?pageNumber={0}'.format(page)" to extract pots, but I don't know how I can connect it to login as the URL is in JSON format.
I would appreciate it if you could help me.

```
import requests, json
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep


url = "https://healthunlocked.com/private/programs/subscribed?user-id=1290456"

payload = {
    
    "username" : "my username goes here",
    "Password" : "my password goes hereh"
    }

s= requests.Session()

p= s.post(url, data = payload)

headers = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0"}
pages =2
data = []

listtitles=[]
listpost=[]
listreplies=[]
listpostID=[]
listauthorID=[]
listauthorName=[]

for page in range(1,pages):
    
    url = 'https://solaris.healthunlocked.com/posts/positivewellbeing/popular?pageNumber= 
    {0}'.format(page)
    r = requests.get(url,headers=headers)

    posts = json.loads(r.text)

    for post in posts:   
        
        sleep(3.5)
        listtitles.append(post['title']) 
   
        listreplies.append(post ["totalResponses"])
        listpostID.append(post["postId"])
        listauthorID.append(post ["author"]["userId"]) 
        listauthorName.append(post ["author"]["username"])
        
        url = 'https://healthunlocked.com/positivewellbeing/posts/{0}'.format(post['postId'])
        r = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
  
        listpost.append(soup.select_one('div.post-body').get_text('|', strip=True))
       
        
 
     ## save to CSV   
        df=pd.DataFrame(list(zip(* 
            [listpostID,listtitles,listpost,listreplies,listauthorID,listauthorName]))).add_prefix('Col')
        df.to_csv('out1.csv',index=False)
        print(df)
        sleep(2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For most websites, you have to first get a token by logging in. Most of the time, this is a cookie. Then, in authorized requests, you can send that cookie along. Open the network tab in developer tools and then log in with your username and password. You'll be able to see how the request is formatted and where it is too. From there, just try to replicate it in your code.

Comment: I am a beginner in web scraping, would you please share a reference for reading